# libapache2-mod-wsgi on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, apache2, uwsgi, moinmoin

I would like to install the MoinMoin wiki on Ubuntu 22.04.2 (jammy) server installation. MoinMoin requires Python 2.7, and WSGI. I would like to install the libapache2-mod-wsgi, but it is unfortunately not available for Ubuntu 22.04.2 (jammy). Note that libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 will not work, because that is specific for Python 3, and MoinMoin needs Python 2.

Is there any way I can get WSGI installed for Python 2 on Ubuntu 22.04.2 (jammy)?

Comment: Two questions: (1) is this an Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server installation? (2) are containers an option?

Comment: It is a server installation, and containers could be an option.

Comment: Containers would make this much simpler. You can use [this Docker configuration](https://github.com/takumaw/moinmoin-docker) to get things up and running. The specified version will likely need to be changed to 1.9.11 beforehand so that you are running the most recent release. The advantage of going with a container is that you will be able to update Ubuntu without worrying about Python 2.x breaking, as it's completely isolated within the Docker container. From here, you can have Apache or nginx set up to proxy traffic to the container 